# $ \underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\lim} \int ^1 _r x^{2013}(\ln x)^{1001} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This integral is in my book, but I don't know how to solve it using simply methods. It's possible to do it clever.

$$ \underset{r \rightarrow 0+}{\lim} \int ^1 _r x^{2013}(\ln x)^{1001} dx$$

Could You help me, how?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book is this?

Comment: If you know how to integrate by parts, consider that you will generate an anti-derivative that produces terms which all look like $ \ x^m (\ln x)^n \ $ with $m$ and $n$ being integers, _except_ the very last one.  What is $ \ 1^m (\ln 1)^n \ $? What is the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x^m (\ln x)^n \ $? What does the last integral look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = e^{-t}$. This gives us $dx = -e^{-t} dt$. We then get
$$\lim_{r \to 0^+}\int_r^1 x^{2013} \ln^{1001}(x) dx = -\int_0^{\infty} t^{1001}e^{-2014t}dt$$
Now make the substitution $2014t = y$ and see how it relates to the [$\Gamma$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: but it's not equal $\Gamma(1000)$, because of wrong number over $e$. How to use this knowledge?

Comment: OK I see. Thanks!